# sql join -vs- where clause not producing the same result?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am a bit boggled as to why these two SQL constructs do not yield the same result.

SQL#1 return 2 identical records (dups) when only one exists in the defects table... see next sql

```
SELECT  * 
FROM Defects d
    JOIN StatusCode C ON C.CodeName = d.Status AND c.scid = 10
WHERE d.AssignedTo='me'
```

SQL#2 reruns 1 record - this is correct cause lookign at raw data there is one defect not closed for 'me'

```
SELECT  * 
FROM Defects d
WHERE d.AssignedTo='me' AND Status <> 'closed'
```

all i am doing is instead of using a negative where status not in something , using a positive by way of the join to records that have every value defect status other than closed

why does this happen, and how can i alter my select with the join to corect its result. i tried using `DISTINCT` but it fails with:

> The ntext data type cannot be selected
>   as DISTINCT because it is not
>   comparable.

there are no status codes that are 'closed', not a single one:

```
select * from StatusCode where scid = 10
```

results in these values:
Fixed
New
Ready for Retest
Failed Retest
Quality Follow Up
Reopen
Rejected
Consumer
In Coding
Open
Fixed
New
Ready for Retest
Failed Retest
Quality Follow Up
Reopen
Rejected
Consumer
In Coding
Open

Comment: I see you have ntext fields in your database. You need to start replacing these with nvarchar (max) as ntext is deprecated and will not be in the next version of SQL Server after 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner join will return *all* matching combinations of rows, so there must be *two* rows in the StatusCode table that match the "Status" value of your Defect (and have scid = 10).

Fixed
New
Ready for Retest
Failed Retest
Quality Follow Up
Reopen
Rejected Consumer
In Coding
Open
Fixed
New
Ready for Retest
Failed Retest
Quality Follow Up
Reopen
Rejected Consumer
In Coding
Open

Not sure if I parsed your list exactly right, but there do appear to be duplicates. The answer, then, is to either eliminate the duplicates in the StatusCode table, or apply an additional filter to distinguish between them if the duplicates are valid.

Comment: you are correct, so my sql thinking was correct and the data was at fault for the error. good catch. thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

How many rows are returned by this?

```
SELECT * FROM StatusCode C WHERE c.scid = 10
```

You may therefore want to do this:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM Defects d
WHERE d.AssignedTo='me' AND d.Status IN (
    SELECT C.CodeName FROM StatusCode C WHERE C.scid = 10
)
```

*Edit to address your edit:* since you have multiple states with `scid=10`, each of those will be joined to your rows, which is why you get the duplicates. My code suggestion is still valid though.

Comment: using the IN is the same as doing a join to eliminate unwanted records, right? that is to say you can use a IN ('Fixed', 'New', 'Ready for Retest'....) to get a result that excludes defects where status <> closed AKA where status = all options other than closed. as well as join to the same set to get an exclusion.

Comment: The `JOIN` will create all matching combinations, which is not what you want. The `IN` on the other hand just like another `WHERE` predicate and will return true if the value specified is contained in the `IN ()` set.

Answer (score -2):

I would think the problem is here:

```
JOIN StatusCode C ON C.CodeName = d.Status AND c.scid = 10
```

The c.scid = 10 should be in the where clause.

Comment: This is perfectly valid as a join condition, and since it is an inner join this means that conditions not met will skip the row, which is (in this particular case) just the same as having it in the `WHERE` clause.